# Why we need distcp command to copy data from hdfs to s3, when we can directly write the data to s3 location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

Please help me understand the use of distcp, we are using s3 and in some scripts I can see they are directly writing data to s3 and many cases writing data to hdfs and then using distcp to copy data to s3.

So when to use distcp and when can we write to cloud directly?

Comment: Your question does not make too much sense. You can use HDFS or S3 to store data. Both have legitimate use cases and different trade offs.  Data operations can directly address S3 or HDFS by using the fully qualified path in Hadoop. You can even configure Hadoop to use S3 as default FS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to be very clear why to use distcp.

Distcp is mainly used to transfer across hadoop cluster. Lets say you have two remote hadoop cluster 1 in California and other 1 is in Arizona and cluster1 is your primary cluster and cluster2 is your secondary means that you are doing all the processing on cluster1 and dumping new data to cluster2 once the processing is completed on cluster2.

In this scenrio you will distcp(copy) you data from cluster1 to cluster2 because both cluster are different and you can copy your data very fast as it copies data in parallel using mappers. So you can think of **distcp** as similar to ftp which is used for local data copy across different servers.

In your case i think hdfs you mentioned is other hadoop cluser from which you are copying your data to aws s3 or vice versa.

Hope it clears your doubt